# UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I'm trying to figure out what collation I should be using for various types of data. 100% of the content I will be storing is user-submitted.

My understanding is that I should be using UTF-8 General CI (Case-Insensitive) instead of UTF-8 Binary. However, I can't find a clear a distinction between UTF-8 General CI and UTF-8 Unicode CI.

1. Should I be storing user-submitted content in UTF-8 General or UTF-8 Unicode CI columns?
2. What type of data would UTF-8 Binary be applicable to?

Comment: Side note but instead of `utf8`, use `utf8mb4` instead for full UTF-8 support. Commenting here because the answers on this popular question do not address this. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Or click "Affects Me" on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58797 and add a comment.

Comment: _Now that 8.0 is common, much of this Question and the Answers are out of date_.  (Feel free to start a new Question to get a more targeted answer.)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

In general, *utf8_general_ci* is faster than *utf8_unicode_ci*, but less correct.

Here is the difference:

> For any Unicode character set, **operations performed using the _general_ci collation are faster than those for the _unicode_ci collation**. For example, comparisons for the utf8_general_ci  collation are faster, but slightly less correct, than comparisons for utf8_unicode_ci. The reason for this is that utf8_unicode_ci supports mappings such as expansions; that is, when one character compares as equal to combinations of other characters. For example, in German and some other languages “ß” is equal to “ss”. utf8_unicode_ci also supports contractions and ignorable characters. utf8_general_ci  is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters. It can make only one-to-one comparisons between characters.

Quoted from:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

For more detailed explanation, please read the following post from MySQL forums:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748

As for utf8_bin:
Both *utf8_general_ci* and *utf8_unicode_ci* perform case-insensitive comparison. In constrast, **utf8_bin is case-sensitive** (among other differences), because it compares the binary values of the characters.

Comment: I think that if you don't have a good reason to use _unicode_ci, then use _general_ci.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in depth though. *What is the difference between these collations exactly?*

Comment: You are right, the exact difference is not provided here for sake of simplicity. I've added a link to a post with the *exact* difference.

Comment: NB `show collation;` allows you to see the default collation for each character set. 5.1 shows `utf8_general_ci` as default for `utf8`.

Comment: Are there any resources that would go more in-depth in the actual speed difference between the two collations? Are we talking about a 0.1% drop in performance or a 10% drop?

Comment: Does utf8-bin collation means exact binary match?

Answer (score 93):

You should also be aware of the fact, that with utf8_general_ci when using a varchar field as unique or primary index inserting 2 values like 'a' and 'á' would give a duplicate key error.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to avoid similar usernames (e.g. if "jose" exists, I wouldn't want someone else to create a "josé" user) NB: this also holds true for most of the utf8 collations (except utf8_bin). The surest/safest/most comprehensive is `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: I use utf8_bin where I want jose and josé to be distinguished in the index. For example, a column that records search/replace operations, where the user might have decided to search for josé, and replace it with jose. (I'm writing a spreadsheet program)

Answer (score 47):

- `utf8_bin` compares the bits blindly.  No case folding, no accent stripping.
- `utf8_general_ci` compares one codepoint with one codepoint.  It does case folding *and* accent stripping, but no 2-character comparisons; for example: `ij` is not equal `ĳ` in this collation.
- `utf8_*_ci` is a set of language-specific rules, but otherwise like `unicode_ci`.  Some special cases: `Ç`, `Č`, `ch`, `ll`
- `utf8_unicode_ci` follows an old Unicode standard for comparisons. `ij`=`ĳ`, but `ae` != `æ`
- `utf8_unicode_520_ci` follows a newer Unicode standard.  `ae` = `æ`

See [collation chart](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) for details on what is equal to what in various utf8 collations.

`utf8`, *as defined by MySQL*, is limited to the 1- to 3-byte utf8 codes.  This leaves out Emoji and some of Chinese.  So you should really switch to `utf8mb4` if you want to go much beyond Europe.

The above points apply to `utf8mb4`, after suitable spelling change.  Going forward, `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` are preferred.  Or (in 8.0) `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

- utf16 and utf32 are variants on utf8; there is virtually no use for them.
- ucs2 is closer to "Unicode" than "utf8"; there is virtually no use for it.

Comment: Re "stay tuned": [_8.0 collations_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) shows how various characters, diphthongs, etc, compare in the 8.0 utf8mb4 collations; utf8 is mostly the same.

Comment: And 8.0 collations are clocked at being _significantly_ faster than 5.x.

Comment: it would be nice if that page lists utf8mb4_bin at the top. I know it does no character matching at all, but it's good for newbies.

Comment: @TobySpeight - Thanks.  Now I am worried that I messed up on other answers; I have said things like that many times in the last decade.  Now that 8.0 is the current version, many questions like this are not asked -- general_ci is not the default anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer is outdated.

If you use MySQL 5.5.3+, use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead of `utf8_unicode_ci` to ensure the characters typed by your users won't give you errors.

`utf8mb4` supports emojis for example, whereas `utf8` might give you hundreds of encoding-related bugs like:

`Incorrect string value: ‘\xF0\x9F\x98\x81…’ for column ‘data’ at row 1`

Comment: This Answer (correctly) addresses issues with encoding of Emoji (and some of Chinese).  But the Question seems to be focused on Collation.  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` treats (I think) all Emoji as equal.  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` gives an ordering to Emoji.

Answer (score 6):

Really, I tested saving values like 'é' and 'e' in column with **unique** index and they cause duplicate error on both 'utf8_unicode_ci' and 'utf8_general_ci'. You can save them only in 'utf8_bin' collated column.

And mysql docs (in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html) suggest into its examples set 'utf8_general_ci' collation.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: I did a quick test on this, and it appears to be accurate. Both collations behave the same when it comes to a unique key on a column and values with tildes and the like.

Comment: @MirroredFate OK, I should add there that column should have unique index for causing  this error. It implies in my answer.