# How to write a php search script in which words with diacritics match search terms without diacritics, and the results are underlined?

Tags: language-agnostic, search, full-text-search, highlighting, diacritics

I've got this site where there are lots of texts with diacritics in them (ancillary glyphs  added to letters, according to wikipedia) and most people search these texts using words without the glyphs. Now it shouldn't be challenging to do this by having a copy of the texts without diacritics. However, I want to highlight the matches in the original text.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Use http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: thank you, i'll look into it in more detail; however i'm looking for a language-agnostic solution, one that wouldn't involve importing a library; i'm more of a php person than a .net person anyways

Comment: Are you using a MySQL back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try changing the collation setting in your MySQL DB.

There are three that seem to come up often in discussions of this topic:

1. `utf8_general_ci`
2. `utf8_unicode_ci`
3. `utf8_bin` ← You probably want this one.

I have found that #3 will match accents in search. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode) gives a bit of background on the differences, but it doesn't mention the fact that `utf8_bin` is also sensitive to accents. You might want to try all three so you can test for yourself if it's working with the language/script you're dealing with.

To be really sure that things are going to match correctly, you will have to look into Unicode Normalization as well, which is really a whole different ball of wax. It is possible that your user could type in a query with an accent in a different normalization from the one your data is stored in, and thus it might fail to match. I've had that problem with Sqlite, not sure if it applies to MySQL or not.

FWIW, here's a `CREATE TABLE` I'm currently using, where I needed to match accents, that is setting the COLLATION:

```
CREATE TABLE `glosses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `morphemes` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `labels` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `phrase_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nth_word` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

You can see the `COLLATE=utf8_bin` tacked on at the end.

Comment: even though it's not language-agnostic, using a collation seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: Hi altvali. What do you mean by language-agnostic? You mean human-language-agnostic?

Comment: I suppose MySQL isn't a language :) But what I was thinking about is a solution that can work with PHP + MySQL, Python + PostgreSQL, C# + SQLite, or any other combination of language and DB. And my conclusion is that in all cases saving the text in an appropriate collation is the simplest way to do it because searching for a keyword through the text will take the minimum amount of time.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Yeah, as far as I can tell this sort of thing (dealing with diacritics) can get hairy fast. From what I can tell Sqlite's support for Unicode is worse than MySQL's.