# What is the best MySQL collation for German language

Tags: mysql, encoding, collation

I am building a web site in German language, So I will be using characters like `ä, ü, ß` etc., So what are your recommendations?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> This answer is outdated. For full emoji support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325386/2898712).

As the character set, if you can, definitely UTF-8.

As the collation - that's a bit nasty for languages with special characters. There are various types of collations. They can all store all Umlauts and other characters, but they differ in how they treat Umlauts in comparisons, i.e. whether

```
u = ü
```

is true or false; and in sorting (where in the alphabets the Umlauts are located in the sorting order).

To make a long story short, your best bet is either

**`utf8_unicode_ci`**

It allows case insensitive searches; It treats `ß` as `ss` and uses DIN-1 sorting. Sadly, like all non-binary Unicode collations, it treats `u = ü` which is a terrible nuisance because a search for "Muller" will also return "Müller". You will have to work around that by setting a Umlaut-aware collation in real time.

or **`utf8_bin`**

This collation does not have the `u = ü` problem but only case sensitive searches are possible.

I'm not entirely sure whether there are any other side effects to using the binary collation; I asked a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have).

---

[This mySQL manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html) gives a good overview over the various collations and  the consequences they bring in everyday use.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) is a general overview on available collations in mySQL.

Comment: I know this is super old, but... I am trying to apply a utf8 collation similar to what you have above. However, when using utf8_unicode_ci the character 'é' encodes to '?'. Do you have any idea why that is? I thought utf8 had a representation for every character.

Comment: @Pekka, Since `utf8` is flawed (not true unicode), why do you recommend it over `utf8mb4`?

Comment: As of 2019 the correct answer is below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325386/2898712

Comment: @wedi I can't change the accepted answer but that one is definitely better.

Answer (score 18):

To support the **complete UTF-8 standard** you have to use the charset `utf8mb4` and the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` in MySQL!

**Note:** MySQL only supports 1- to 3-byte characters when using its so called `utf8` charset! This is why the modern Emojis are not supported as they use 4 Bytes!

The only way to fully support the UTF-8 standard is to change the charset and collation of ALL **tables** and of the **database** itself to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Further more, the database **connection** needs to use utf8mb4 as well.

The mysql server must use utf8mb4 as default charset which can be manually configured in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
# character-set-client-handshake = FALSE  ## better not set this!
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Existing tables can be migrated to utf8mb4 using the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> CONVERT TO 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Note:

- To make sure any JOINs between table-colums will not be slowed down by charset-encodings ALL tables have to be change!
- As the length of an index is limited in MySQL, the total number of characters per index-row must be multiplied by 4 Byte and need to be smaller than 3072

> When the innodb_large_prefix configuration option is enabled, this
>   length limit is raised to 3072 bytes, for InnoDB tables that use the
>   DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED row formats.

To change the charset and default collation of the database, run this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Since utf8mb4 is fully backwards compatible with utf8, no mojibake or other forms of data loss should occur.

Answer (score 3):

`utf-8-general-ci` or `utf-8-unicode-ci`.

To know the difference : 
[UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)

Comment: I think you mean `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Answer (score 3):

The above comments aren't really addressing the specific problem with German umlauts, which is often described as: dictionary order or phone-book order? The Unicode default is okay for the former but if (e.g.) you want 'Ü' = 'UE' then you could consider utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci or utf8mb4_german2_ci, assuming character set is utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing, because this is about the german language. with **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** the letters **u** and **ü** are the same. if you have a unique index (e.g. for usernames), then "**blume**" and "**blüme**" will not work, since they are the same word for utf8mb4_unicode_ci (*duplicate key error*). to work around the problem, you can use **utf8mb4_german2_ci**