# MySQL: ss and ß in LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any solution that MySQL can automatically handle `ss` and `ß` in `LIKE` statements? In a statement with equals `=` it works, but we have a search text field so the term is not equal to the search data in the database.

Only to change the collation of the database has not solved the problem, because it will only work for equal statements (`=`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best MySQL collation for German language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526169/what-is-the-best-mysql-collation-for-german-language)

Comment: @NicoVanBelle: Please see the question update; it's not a duplicate because the change of collation seems insufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE()` on the field you're comparing.  Something like this:

```
WHERE REPLACE(YourField, 'ß', 'ss') LIKE '%ss'
```

Comment: Will it prevent the use of an index by `YourField`, if it exists?

Comment: @9000 Yep it will.  I still prefer it to the German collation option, since I think having umlaut comparisons being equal, ex. `u = ü`, is a huge problem.  But if there are significant slowdowns, that could be handled in many ways, such as creating another indexed column with the replaced character field.

Comment: @aaron-diez Too bad MySQL does not support functional indexes. When [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380963/223424) is not sufficient, probably a proper full-text indexing server is the right answer.

Comment: This will become horrible slow if you have a big dataset.