# Laravel PHP invalid string problem while inserting data to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert data from a CSV file to the database and everything is working but if any string comes with any German special character like öüäß then I get the following error displayed:

```
b"SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE4.' for column 'name' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ergebnisses` (`stadt`, `lauf_jahr`, ▶"
```

controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $collection = (new FastExcel)->configureCsv(';')->import('C:\Users\mussa\Desktop\file.csv', function ($line) {
            return Ergebnisse::create([
                'stadt' => 'hamburg',
                'lauf_jahr' => '2019',
                'lauf_strecke' => '4',
                'MWPl' => $line['MWPl'],
                'start_number' => $line['Startnr.'],
                'name' => $line['Name'],
                'birth_year' => $line['Jahrg.'],
                'm/w' => $line['m/w'],
                'AK' => $line['AK'],
                'verein' => $line['Verein'],
                'zeit' => $line['Zeit'],
            ]);
        });
        // dd($collection);
    }
```

Collection data:

[image: Collection data]

any help would be really appreciated, I am new to Laravel.

Best Regards
Musayyab Naveed

Comment: maybe [using the charset utf8mb4 and the collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526169/what-is-the-best-mysql-collation-for-german-language/48325386#48325386) ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your column datatype **string** instead of **DateTime**

**Or**

If you don't want to change your column datatype then enter date in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datatype "string" in migration for name column