# In phpMyAdmin missing Character sets and collations

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The server in phpmyadmin is missing Character sets and collations.

E.g. There is no utf8_german2_ci, utf8_myanmar_ci, utf8_spanish2_ci, utf8_vietnamese_ci

I mainly need utf8_german2_ci.

How can Character sets be added?

[image]

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526169/what-is-the-best-mysql-collation-for-german-language) says it's better to use `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I would like to use utf8_german2 if MySQL already contains it. Maybe I figured it out. I have version `10.1.28-MariaDB` on localhost and it contains it. We have `5.5.65-MariaDB` on the server. I'll agree to update MySQL and let you know.