# mysql column data type - which datatype to use that accepts special letters or chars?

Tags: mysql

I have entered in my form this data to test "Do Goldenen Schlüssel" and successfully saved to table,. However, when output in another page it is now "DoGoldenen SchlÃ¼ssel".
My datatype is only Varchar. Could you help me to specify which solution to be adjusted on my table in order to correctly accepts these kind of strings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to be a problem with encoding, not data type.

Comment: Maybe take a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526169/what-is-the-best-mysql-collation-for-german-language . I think it might be a collation problem