# MySQL - Proper "Collation" for case-sensitive text? UTF8-bin?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

In using MySQL (v5.0.77) there are a lot of choices for Collation. I was originally thinking of **UTF8-general_ci** however MySQL shows it as being case-insensitive which I think would cause problems for objects such as passwords. If I want to use UTF8 but want case-sensitive data should I use **UTF8-bin**? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `utf8_bin`.

A hint. When the colation ends with CS it means "Case Sensitive". For example: `utf8_croatian_cs` is Case Sensitive.

Comment: More info here at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode