# Finding the perfect database collation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, collation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)

I'm running some tests on finding the right collation for the right table. Is it correct to assume that if a table were to contain user submitted data (profiles info, etc.) or authentication data (hashes, etc.) a collation of `utf8_bin` would work well while all the rest can be in `utf8_general_ci` which is faster?

Or should everything just be the same collation?

Comment: [UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)

Comment: Why would case and diacritic insensitive comparisons be more performant than direct binary comparisons