# MySQL thinks "e" is the same as "é"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following columns:

ID
name

Both are indexed, both must be unique.

One post has name "ussé".

I try to insert a new post with the name "usse" and get the following error:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.16-log]Duplicate entry 'usse' for key 'name'.
```

What the...? MySQL can't tell those two strings apart?

Is there some way to fix this?

All my text fields have "utf8 - default collation" selected. Does this make a difference? If I need to change it to something else, is there a way to do it quickly for all tex fields in all databases? There are so many that I would like to avoid going through them manually if I can.

My connection string:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=example; UID=example; PASSWORD=example; OPTION=3;
```

Comment: Is name the primary key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode

Comment: name isn't primary key, ID is primary key

Comment: What is the collation (not the encoding) of your database (or the columns if you changed it on column level)

Comment: Where can I see that? I just started using MySQL (auto-imported a bunch of tables) so I'm wet behind my ears. All I know is that my table's have "utf8 - default collation" and the fields have "Table Default" as collation. I don't know how to set the default collation for the whole database.

Comment: I just checked the schema that contains all the tables and it also has "utf8 - default collation" as collation. Which means it gets the value from somewhere else? I don't know how to find that setting in MySQL workbench 6.0 that I'm using.

Comment: hehe, somebody just removed an incorrect answer after he posted a confusing reply... dont remember the user name though

Comment: If ID is primary key then why got an error as "Duplicate entry 'usse' for key 'name'" i tried inserting in my local db it inserted correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here : 
[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

here's a list of commands :

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```