# Best mysql collation if I expects ñ ü ï á é í ó ú

Tags: mysql, database, collation

I've been surfing on the web to find the best collation for my website if I expects values that contains especial characters like `ñ ü ï á é í ó ú Ü Ä Ï...` and others characters in German and Portuguese.

I don't use `utf8_bin` because I need the collation to be case insensitive(mostly because of search Purpouses). What's the best collation for this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)

Comment: Collation isn't charset. You're looking for charset. Collation is a set of rules for sorting alphabet characters.

Comment: You need to let us know whether your audience is mostly `es`. The collation differs a bit for Spanish and most other European languages.

Answer (score 0):

A case-insensitive collation is one that ends with `_ci`, such as `utf8_general_ci`.

Note that if you want the characters to be correctly sorted, you need to choose a collation specific to your language, such as `utf8_german_ci`. This might cause text in other languages to be *incorrectly* sorted. If you are mixing languages in your database, you will have to pick whatever collation produces the least awkward results.

See also the MySQL documentation:

- [10.1 Character Sets and Collations in General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html)
- [10.10 Supported Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html)
- [10.10.1 Unicode Character Sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)