# Select with Utf-8 in MySQL return wrong results

Tags: mysql, select, encoding, utf-8

When I excute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `PageMapLine` WHERE name = "không"
```

The result include unexpected records like "Khổng" and "Khong":

```
id      name    pageID  stem    lemma
--------------------------------------
236040  Khổng   236040  NULL    NULL
494405  Không   494405  NULL    NULL
796340  Khong   796340  NULL    NULL
--------------------------------------
```

My table encoding was utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your ci (case insensitive) codification. I would use utf8_bin instead. Remember to backup first.

Case insensitive is also insensitive to those special characters.

Comment: But I want my query case insensitive then how can I do?

Comment: @Kim Have you tried with utf8_unicode_ci? Take a look here, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode

Comment: @Kim Did you solved your problem? If so, please mark the question as answered. Thank you