# Getting duplicate entry errors when converting utf-8 database to utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, unique-index, utf8mb4

I'm trying to convert a database to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8. Everything is going fine except one table:

```
CREATE TABLE `search_terms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `search_term` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `time_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `search_term` (`search_term`),
  KEY `search_term_count` (`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=198981 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Basically all it does is save an entry every time somebody searches something in a form so we can track the number of searches, very simple.

There's a unique index on `search_term` because we want to only have one row per search term and instead increment the count value.

However when converting to utf8mb4 I am getting duplicate entry errors. Here is the command I am running:

```
ALTER TABLE `search_terms` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Looking in the database I can see various examples like this:

> ｆｍ２０１２
>
> ｆｍ2012
>
> fm2012

In it's current utf8 character set, these are all being treated as unique and exist within the database without ever having an issue with the unique index on `search_term`.

But when converting to utf8mb4 they are now being considered equal and throwing an error due to that index.

I can figure out how to merge these together easily enough, but i'm concerned this may be a symptom of a greater underlying problem. I'm not really sure how this has happened or what the consequences may be, so my questions are a bit vague:

1. Why is utf8mb4 treating these differently to utf8?
2. What are the possible consequences?
3. Is there someway I can do a conversion so things like "ｆｍ２０１２" never appear in my database and I only have "fm2012" (I am also using Laravel 5.1)

Comment: That looks more like UTF-32 and UTF-16 to be honest. It's odd the conversion does that. Does this happen on trivial test tables?

Comment: Could you please paste your error?

Comment: What's the collation before the conversion and are these really spaces in your example string "fm2012"? Can you get us the hex dump?

Comment: @NishantNair it's a simple "Duplicate entry 'fm2012' for key 'seach_term'"

Comment: @Beat it's "utf8_general_ci" and as far I can tell it's not spaces. It appears exactly as it appears in this SO question. I'm not sure what you mean by the hex dump

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the change of collation: you're using `general_ci` and you're converting to `unicode_ci`: `general_ci` is quite a simple collation that doesn't know much about unicode, but `unicode_ci` does.

The first "ｆ" in your example string is a "Fullwidth Latin Small Letter F" (U+FF46) which is considered equal to "Latin Small Letter F" (U+0066) by `unicode_ci` but not by `general_ci`.

Normally it's recommended to use `unicode_ci` exactly because of its unicode-awareness but you could convert to `utf8mb4_general_ci` to prevent this problem.

To prevent this problem in the future, you should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) your input before saving it in the DB. Normally you'd use NFC, but your case seems to call for NFKC. This should bring all "equivalent" strings to the same form.

Comment: Ah, thanks alot that makes sense.

Are there any other differences in using utf8mb4_general_ci instead of utf8mb4_unicode_ci? It seems like a good opportunity to make the switch but I guess it could also cause more problems.

Comment: There are many differences, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2344130/853468

Answer (score 1):

Despite what was said previously it is not about `general_ci` being more simplistic than `unicode_ci`. Yes, it can be true, but the issue is that you need to keep it matching to the sub-type you have.

For example, my database is `utf8_bin`. I cannot convert to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` nor to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. These commands will throw an error of a duplicate key being found. However the correct collation `utf8mb4_bin` completes without issues.