# PHP mySql encoding for german letters

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple function to display genman texts from database.
I get bad output on HTML :
That's the output in HTML (you can see **wei�** instead of **weiß**)
[image]

My HTML head :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="latin1">
```

I tried `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1` didn't work as well, same bad character

The data in my PHPMyQdmin table looks fine:
[image]

This is the structure of my table (field `cName`):

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
I tried to force the encoding in the SELECT query but didn't get the right result too :

```
SELECT column1, CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_condition;
```

**UPDATE 2**
this is my PDO connection :

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=cmondo;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Why are you using `latin1_swedish_ci` encoding for UTF8 German symbols?

Comment: yes, you can see the table structure picture

Comment: `latin1_swedish_ci` is wrong for UTF8 German symbols you should use `uft8_general_ci` or `utf8_bin`

Comment: I changed it in my table  but I still get the same HTML output

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: FWIW, `latin1_swedish_ci` is the ***collation***, meaning text will be sorted by Swedish dictionary rules when sorted and such; largely that doesn't have any influence on anything. The `latin1` part denotes the encoding, and `latin1` can perfectly store German characters. Everyone getting upset about the "swedish" part here is on the wrong track entirely. The crux of the matter is, as in 99% of all such question, the ***connection encoding*** set in your PDO connection.

Comment: See my update, my PDO connection uses utf8

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are using **latin1_swedish_ci.** You have to use either **utf-8-general-ci** or **utf-8-unicode-ci.**

To know the difference : 
[UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode)

Also add the following in your file

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and check which encoding your web server sends in the header.

If you use PHP, you can send your own headers in this way (you have to put this before any other output):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Also check that you saved your file in UTF-8 format.

Comment: I get error to switch to utf8, '#1366 incorrect string value .....' !!!

Comment: I changed, but my HTML output still the same

Comment: Try this if you are getting incorrect string value error ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Still didn't work, I changed the table encoding, added the <META> you gave me. still the same strange letter �

Comment: Have you set character set in your connection?

Comment: Use this if your are using mysqli. 
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Comment: I am using PDO, I think the problem is in the html charset, when I change the encoding in Firefox manually to Western, I get the right display. Unicode is detected but didn't display correctly the letters

Comment: use this in your connection if your are using pdo.
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"

Comment: I did, Same :/ as I said I think the problem is in displaying the data in HTML charset