# How can I build a support ticket system with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ticket-system, ticket-tracking

I have a custom and simple [php](/questions/tagged/php)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) based user system. I'm trying to build a way for members to send product support to our staff (put it in a database & viewed in admin area) and for them to manage these messages.

Does anyone know of a good existing script, or a better approach for a support area of my website?

Comment: Seriously, this is a good question that was useful to me. So +1 :)

Comment: can't believe this one didn't get flagged, maybe the flag "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library.." wasn't available back then? Shouldn't this question be closed with a comment like this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/367711/3664960 got?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ticketing systems are a pretty easy build, have a database table:

```
tickets
id int(11)
user_id int(11)
message text
is_active tinyint(1)
created_at datetime
time_spent int(5) //unless your going to spend more than 99999 mins on a ticket
```

Now each time a user creates a ticket it goes into the db as `VALUES(id,'$user_id','$message',0,NOW(),0)//remember to clean the vars`

Admin can complete a ticket, update the field so that is_active = 1, then request time spent from the admin and update time_spent = '$time_spent'

You could add a commenting system simply

```
Database table: comments
id int(11)
ticket_id int(11)
user_id int(11)
comment text
created_at datetime
```

This way you can have unlimited(up to a total total of 99999999999) comments per ticket and you track the user id so you can put names next to each comment.

You can call the comments using

`select * from comments where ticket_id = $id //the current tickets id`

I hope this helps, its a nice easy build and means you know exactly how it works, its always nice to have done it yourself and its easily customisable.

Regards Luke

Comment: Basecamp is what most people use, but its way bigger than you need if you just want a ticket system, have a look here http://pm-sherpa.com/features/basecamp-alternatives/ I cant recomend one because I havent used any.  Hope it helps

Luke

Comment: Ended up using Basecamp... thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [osTicket](http://osticket.com) which is open source and free.

Answer (score 3):

Or use Spiceworks. It's free.