# Drupal 7 - case-insensitive LIKE with db_select

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, case-insensitive

I can't get a query to be case-insensitive using MySQL and Drupal 7.  Here's my module code:

```
$results = db_select('people_table', 'p')->fields('p');
if (array_key_exists('department', $_GET)) {
    $results->condition('Department', '%' . db_like($_GET['department']) . '%', 'LIKE');
}
return $results->orderBy('Name', 'ASC')->execute();
```

With `?department=Chemistry` in the URL, I get three results.  With `?department=chemistry` in the URL, I get no results.  When I try `$results->condition('UPPER(Department)'...`, I get this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UPPERDepartment' in 'where clause': SELECT p.* FROM {people_table} p WHERE (UPPERDepartment LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\\') ORDER BY Name ASC;

So it looks like it eats my parentheses.  How can I do a case-insensitive `LIKE`?

**Edit:**  the collation on the `Department` column as well as on the whole table is `utf8_bin`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php/367725#367725) says "The only special one is utf8_bin which is for comparing characters in binary format."  I don't know why this collation was chosen, since all the data in the table is English text.  I might just change the collation to [utf8_general_ci](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).

Comment: You have an SQL-injection in your code, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain I guess you've managed to bypass the PDO successfully :-)

Comment: `LIKE` is always case insensitive BTW, even on a binary collation.

Comment: How is there a SQL injection here?  I thought the point of using the `condition()` function with `db_select()` is that it would escape your input.

Comment: @SarahVessels: there is no SQL injection vulnerability here don't worry about it, PDO and the Drupal database layer protect you fully as you suspect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is collation of Department field?, it should be with prefix *_ci (case insensitive) for ex utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: `utf8_bin`.  It's a `longtext`.

Comment: Checking the collation was the right answer.  I changed all the text fields from `utf8_bin` to `utf8_general_ci` and now `$results->condition('Department', '%' . db_like($_GET['department']) . '%', 'LIKE');` works fine.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `condition` you can use the `where` method to add a custom `WHERE` clause:

```
$results->where('UPPER(Department)'...
```

Comment: Well, I didn't get any errors, but I also didn't get any results.  :/  `$results->where("UPPER(Department) LIKE '%:dept%'", array(':dept' => db_like($_GET['department'])));`

Comment: You need to wrap $_GET['department'] in strtoupper or you're just testing an uppercase string with a normal string

Comment: Derp, that would probably do the trick...  I think your solution may have worked as well, though changing the collation seemed a better fix since the original `utf8_bin` made no sense.  Using `condition()` seems a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yeah changing the collation is definitely the right way to go then you won't need to mess about with case sensitivity every time you run a  `LIKE` query

Answer (score 0):

To search case insensitive do following in drupal 7

```
$query->where('UPPER(Department) LIKE :dept',  array('dept' => '%'.db_like($keyword).'%'));
$result = $query->execute();
```