# MySQL Sort Order - Collation?

Tags: mysql, sorting, collation

I'm having a difficult time sorting a char field in MySQL. The problem is that accented characters get mixed up with un-accented characters.  For example:

```
Abc
Ábd
Acc
```

I thought it may have something to do with collation.  So I changed the collation of my table to `utf8-ut8_bin`, after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php).  Actually, I altered the table several times to various collations.  No cigar.

I should also add that, I don't mind the order of the sort as long as the sort doesn't result in a mixed list.  In other words, this is fine:

```
Ábd
Abc
Acc
```

and so is this:

```
Abc
Acc
Ábd
```

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: And how do you want them to be sorted? According to which collation?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the original post to describe the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a case-sensitive collation, for example: `utf8_general_cs`.

**UPD**

I am sorry, [it seems](https://serverfault.com/questions/137415/change-collation-of-a-mysql-table-to-utf8-general-cs) there is no `utf8_general_cs`, `utf8_bin` should work though.

And you should change the collation of the specific field instead of that of the table (or be sure that the field does use the table defaults).

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (
    -> SELECT 'A' as l
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 'á' as l
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 'A' as l) ls
    -> ORDER BY l;
+----+
| l  |
+----+
| A  |
| á  |
| A  |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM (
    -> SELECT 'A' as l
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 'á' as l
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 'A' as l) ls
    -> ORDER BY l COLLATE utf8_bin;
+----+
| l  |
+----+
| A  |
| A  |
| á  |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I had altered the schema and the table to collation utf8_bin and still it wouldn't work.  Then I ran your query and got an error.  Looked at the column and the column had the default collation.  I altered the column to utf8_bin then it worked.  Thanks again.

Comment: This approach fails to account for _equality_.

Answer (score 0):

@newtower had a good starting point, but neither he, nor the 'Community' realized that it was inconclusive.  So I am providing an answer that should 'fix' it:

unicode_ci (and virtually all other collations):

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l SEPARATOR '=') AS gc
  FROM (
    SELECT 'A' as l  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'á' as l  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' as l              ) ls
  GROUP BY l
  ORDER BY gc;

+--------+
| gc     |
+--------+
| A=á=A  |
+--------+
```

bin:

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l SEPARATOR '=') AS gc
  FROM (
    SELECT 'A' as l  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'á' as l  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' as l              ) ls
  GROUP BY l
  ORDER BY gc;

+------+
| gc   |
+------+
| A=A  |
| á    |
+------+
```

(You could add a `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` to avoid the dup `A`.)

And here is a full rundown of the utf8 collations (using that technique):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Suggest you click "Affects Me" on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58797