# Sort French Language in ABC Order (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite

I have a list that I am trying to sort in Alphabetical Order. I have retrieved my database with `SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM 'Main Database' ORDER BY Category asc'"`

It correctly alphabetizes the category list but the letter É is at the very bottom of the list, right after T. Is there a way I can set it so the accent É is right after E in the english alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with collation. You need to select the correct one for either your table or column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

check out this answer: [MySQL Sort Order - Collation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491408/mysql-sort-order-collation)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you by chance know how to integrate this with SQLite?

Comment: ooh, sorry my bad. I just assumed MySQL. You might take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906086/problems-ordering-sqlite-by-a-column-with-accented-characters-%C3%81