# How to query with unicode?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this:

```
letter = None

if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'letter' in request.GET:
        letter = request.GET['letter']

if letter is not None:
    items = MyModel.objects.filter(title__istartswith=letter)
```

But for characters like 'Ą', 'Ć' etc. QuerySet returns results as for 'A', 'C', etc.

What can I do this to work?

Comment: Check your DB backend, especially MySQL, for collation rules and encoding. Refs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php , especially the link of the accepted answer.

Comment: I think it's a browser url problem. It's not support unicode, but I'm not sure.