# MySQL UTF-8 coding

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm very confused with the char coding of my database.

I have the database configure with UTF8_general_ci. But If I try to save something in spanish like "león" the content si spoiled then to fix it I have to use utf8_decode before save and when I read I use utf8_encode.

Then the spanish is correct.

Now I have russian users writing in cyrilic and his content is spoiled (with ???????)

I suppose if I don't use utf8_decode the cyrilic will be correct (or not I don't know) but then the spanish will be not correct.

What can I do to save correctly all the languages? I'm very confused.

Comment: What character set does the client/connection use ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run as first statment this sql query:

```
set names 'utf8';
```

This sets the encoding of the MySQL connetion to UTF-8 and prevents a double encoding.

Comment: Thank you!! I've putted after the connection:   mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); and it seems it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your client executes

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

when it starts a session. Check that all tables and all char fields in tables use utf-8 encoding (their encoding can differ from database encoding).

Answer (score 1):

I use a script that converts all the tables in a database for utf8 charsets. Give it a try:

```
<?
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'db_name';
$collation = "utf8_general_ci";
$charset = "utf8";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE $dbname COLLATE $collation");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] COLLATE $collation");
$result1 = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $row[0]");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
if (preg_match('~char|text|enum|set~', $row1["Type"])) {
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] CHARACTER SET $charset");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] COLLATE $collation DEFAULT '$row1[Default]'");
echo $row[0] . "->" . $row1[Field] . "->" . $row1[Type] . " is now UTF8
";
}
}
}
mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thannk you But it's supposed I have the database in UTF-8, I defined the fields in UTF-8 I don't understand why I have to alter the database to UTF-8.

Comment: I've needed a quick solution and I added after the connection   

mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

And it seems works well, I'm more relaxed now.

Now I'll read carefully your links and I'll try to understand the tpasku script.

Thank you, you are awesome!!!

Oscar.

Answer (score 1):

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php
```

mysql character sets -----------------

```
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html
```

you can specify a more specific UTF-8 character set like 'utf8_swedish_ci'

Comment: I've needed a quick solution and I added after the connection   

mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

And it seems works well, I'm more relaxed now.

Now I'll read carefully your links and I'll try to understand the tpasku script.

Thank you, you are awesome!!!

Oscar.