# Does a utf8_unicode_cs collation exist?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Does anyone know if a utf8_unicode_cs collation for MySQL exists? So far, my searches have come up dry. If it simply doesn't exist yet, is it fairly straight-forward to create one? Or somehow use utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_bin but "simulate" what one would expect from a utf8_unicode_cs collation?

Answer (score 13):

I came across the same issue and after some Googling, it seems that MySQL doesn't include it.  To "simulate it", as you put it,

1) **To ensure case-sensitivity in the DB: set the table column to `utf8_bin` collation** 

This allows:

- strict SELECTs:  `SELECT "Joe"` will NOT return rows with "joe" / "joE" / "jOe" / etc
- strict UNIQUE index: a column with a UNIQUE index will treat case differences as different values. For example, if a utf8_unicode_ci collation is used, inserting "Joe" on a table that already has "joe" will trigger a "Duplicate key" error. If ut8_bin is used, inserting "Joe" will work fine.

2) **To get the proper ordering in results: add the collation to the SQL query:**

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but does not seem to be superseded by any other, so I thought it worth posting that things have changed.

MySQL version 8 now has the following collations for utf8mb4:

```
 utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci 
 utf8mb4_0900_as_ci
 utf8mb4_0900_as_cs
 ... and many language-specific variants of same.
```

(no _ai_cs as far as I know, but that would in any case be less useful: few reasons to group [a] and [a-acute] and then separately group [A] and [A-acute]).

The purpose of the original question's hypothetical "utf8_unicode_cs" is fulfilled by utf8mb4_0900_as_cs. (The 0900 means it uses Unicode v 9.0.0 as opposed to 4.0.0 used by utf8_unicode_ci.)

To use these you'd need to change the field from utf8 to utf8mb4 character set - but that's a generally good idea anyway because the old 3-byte-max encoding can't handle e.g. emoji and other non-BMP characters.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html