# What MySQL case-sensitive collation to use for a multilingual website?

Tags: mysql, database, multilingual, collation

The question says it all:

I have a project that needs to be multilingual and need case-sensitivity for the collation.

The database isn't MS-SQL!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Sensitive collation in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I switched from `utf8_bin` to `utf8_unicode_ci` which provides way better ordering of Cyrillic characters than `ut8_general_ci` and definitely better than `utf8_bin` (ordering of Cyrillic characters in `utf8_bin` is very wrong).

As per following Q&A: [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) the only drawback of `utf8_unicode_ci` is performance, but if one doesn't work with millions of rows, I think he/she can ignore performance penalties because accuracy should be way better.

Comment: At the moment I'm using ut8_general_ci, but I need it to be case sensitive(not _ci).

Comment: Ah, ok. Then it seems that for now you'll need to use `utf8_bin` and append `order by column collate utf8_unicode_ci` to each query. See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218077/does-a-utf8-unicode-cs-collation-exist and http://serverfault.com/questions/137415/change-collation-of-a-mysql-table-to-utf8-general-cs