# How to return str from MySQL using mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, utf-8, collation

I'm trying to use MySQL Connector/Python from mysql.com with Python 3.

I have tables in UTF-8 coding, and when I fetch the rows, all my chars columns returned like `bytearray`. This is make some confusion.

How I can fetch directly `str`?

UPD:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect( user ="root", db = "vg_site_db", charset = 'utf8' )
cursor = con.cursor()
sql = """select caption from domains
"""
cursor.execute( sql )
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print( row )
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

output:

```
(bytearray(b'ezsp.ru'),)
(bytearray(b'eazyshop.ru'),)
(bytearray(b'127.0.0.1:8080'),)
(bytearray(b'rmsvet.ru'),)
```

I want:

```
('ezsp.ru',)
('eazyshop.ru',)
('127.0.0.1:8080',)
('rmsvet.ru',)
```

UPD2:

My tables use `COLLATE utf8_bin`.

Comment: show your python code that reads database content

Comment: I update post and add the code samples

Comment: I'm also getting bytearray's from cursor.fetchone() in Python 2.7.  Passing them through `str(row[0].decode())` turned them into native strings in both Python 2.7 and 3.4.  MySQL [made a change](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-0-0.html) in Connector version 2.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like this happens when you use binary collation, at least the same happened to me. To convert the bytearrays to Unicode strings, you can add a custom converter class:

```
class MyConverter(mysql.connector.conversion.MySQLConverter):

    def row_to_python(self, row, fields):
        row = super(MyConverter, self).row_to_python(row, fields)

        def to_unicode(col):
            if isinstance(col, bytearray):
                return col.decode('utf-8')
            return col

        return[to_unicode(col) for col in row]

sql = mysql.connector.connect(converter_class=MyConverter, host=...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works, because converters now have to inherit from `MySQLConverterBase` and that one doesn't have the `row_to_python` method, unless you copy paste it yourself and ugh.

Comment: @Tominator : Sure? It still works for me. Also, `MySQLConverter` extends `MySQLConverterBase` and still has the [`row_to_python` method](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/905a75e589c9d0e32fd54b0aaae7ad07be368859/lib/mysql/connector/conversion.py#L378), so I don't immediately see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Connector returns strings (as stored using the `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` data types) as `bytearray`s when respective columns are defined with a *binary collation* (e.g. `utf8_bin`). You must call `.decode()` on values to get Python strings, e.g.:

```
for row in cursor:
    caption = row[0].decode()
```

That said, unless you have a specific requirement to use `utf8_bin`, it's a much better idea to use the `utf8mb4` character set with the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` on the database level. That would solve your problem and allow for full Unicode support. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475756/244297) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/244297) fore more details.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather recomment `utf8mb_unicode_cs`? As I understand it, `bin` sorts/selects by exact character code, `cs` sorts like a regular user would expect, and `ci` is case insensitive but otherwise like `cs`.

Comment: @lucidbrot There's no `utf8mb_unicode_cs` collation, but perhaps you can use  [`utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-accent-and-case-sensitive-collations-for-utf8mb4/). As for which one is better, it depends. Generally, capital letters are considered to be identical to their corresponding lower case letters for the purposes of [alphabetical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order).

Answer (score 1):

Adding `mysql-connector-python==8.0.17` to requirements.txt resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although the most voted answer (by @danmichaelo) certainly works, I wanted to provide my version that solves a major "but" that is already pointed out by @Tominator; custom converter classes must now inherit `MySQLConverterBase` and not `MySQLConverter`. The reason you do not want to inherit `MySQLConverter` (even if it inherits `MySQLConverterBase` as @danmichaelo points out) is that it will invoke the corresponding converter in the `MySQLConverter` class on each returned value. This will implement a logic you may not want.

To avoid the above, you have two choices. First, you could create a higher-level function that will get the data and alter the rows after they are retrieved.

```py
def get_data_from_db(cursor, sql_query):
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        row_to_return = row.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(row, bytearray) else row
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    
    return row
```

If you still want to use the custom converter class method, then you should inherit the `MySQLConverterBase` as suggested in the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html this is valid until mysql-connector-python==8.0.26, see below) and then you could extend the `MySQLConverterBase.to_python` method.

```py
class MyConverter(mysql.connector.conversion.MySQLConverterBase):
    def to_python(self, vtype, value):
        """Convert MySQL data type to Python"""
        if isinstance(value, bytearray):
            return value.decode('utf-8')

        super().to_python(vtype, value)
```

P.S. The class MyConverter can be used to implement custom converters by creating functions with names as in the `MySQLConverter` class (find the class here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/conversion.py). For example, I was looking to convert TINYINT to bool and added a method named `MyConverter._TINY_to_python(self, value, desc=None)`

-- **Update mysql-connector-python==8.0.27** --

In the 8.0.27 version, if you create a converter class that inherits the MySQLConverterBase you will probably get an error saying *"expected a bytes-like object, str found"*. It is unclear to me why this happens but my answer above on creating the custom converter seems to not hold anymore. Instead, one should inherit the `MySQLConverter` class now:

```py
class MyConverter(mysql.connector.conversion.MySQLConverter):
    def to_python(self, vtype, value):
        """Convert MySQL data type to Python"""
        if isinstance(value, bytearray):
            return value.decode('utf-8')

        super().to_python(vtype, value)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you can get the cursor to return strings. The [MySQL Connector Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-0-0.html) says that they chose to return bytearrays so that they only have to maintain one codebase for both Python2 and Python3:

> With the use of “raw” cursors, the returned values is of the bytearray type. This is necessary for having both Python 2 and 3 return the same data.

I addressed this issue using a list comprehension to decode each bytearray in the row:

```
for row in cursor:
    type_fixed_row = tuple([el.decode('utf-8') if type(el) is bytearray else el for el in row])
    print( type_fixed_row )
```

Comment: *raw* is not enabled by default, so I find this puzzling. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html#idm140343529540800) says "By default, strings coming from MySQL are returned as Python Unicode literals."

Answer (score -2):

An easy way to solve this issue is to make sure that you are retrieving 'strings' from your MySQL table. To do so, you just have to add a CAST in your query as follows:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect( user ="root", db = "vg_site_db", charset = 'utf8' )
cursor = con.cursor()
sql = "select CAST(caption as CHAR(50)) from domains"
cursor.execute( sql )
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print( row )
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

This should work for you.