# Python MySQL connector returns bytearray instead of regular string value

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am loading data from one table into pandas and then inserting that data into new table. However, instead of normal string value I am seeing bytearray.

`bytearray(b'TM16B0I8')` it should be `TM16B0I8`

What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```
engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@localhost/db'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
connection = engine.connect()

th_df = pd.read_sql('select ticket_id, history_date', con=connection)

for row in th_df.to_dict(orient="records"):
    var_ticket_id = row['ticket_id']
    var_history_date = row['history_date']

    query = 'INSERT INTO new_table(ticket_id, history_date)....'
```

Comment: where do you see the bytearray? anywhere related to the code above?

Comment: So when I am printing `th_df['ticket_id']`, instead of giving me a string `'TM16A0JY'` it is giving me this array `[77, 83, 90, 45, 48, 50, 53, 52, 57, 56]` and after the insert when I looked into DB it is showing me `bytearray(b'TM16A0JY')`. Interestingly for integer IDs it is not showing bytearray and also inserting a integer value in db. `4567`.

Answer (score 10):

For some reason the Python MySql connector only returns bytearrys, (more info in ([How return str from mysql using mysql.connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566078/how-return-str-from-mysql-using-mysql-connector))  but you can decode them into unicode strings with

```
var_ticket_id = row['ticket_id'].decode()
var_history_date = row['history_date'].decode()
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are using the right collation, and encoding. I happen to use `UTF8MB4_BIN` for one of my website db tables. Changed it to `utf8mb4_general_ci`, and it did the trick.

Comment: This is perfect - I too had a similar problem that was solved by changing the collation from latin1_bin to    COLLATE latin1_general_ci . Thank you @Yongju Lee

Answer (score 2):

Producing a *bytearray* is now the expected behaviour.

It changed with *mysql-connector-python* 8.0.24 (2021-04-20). According to the [v8.0.24 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-24.html), "*Binary columns were returned as strings instead of 'bytes' or 'bytearray'*" behaviour was a bug that was fixed in that release.

So producing a Python *bytearray* is the correct behaviour, if the database column is a binary type (e.g. *binary* or *varbinary*). Previously, it produced a Python *string*, but now it produces a *bytearray*.

So either change the data type in the database to a non-binary data type, or convert the *bytearray* to a *string* in your code. If the column is nullable, you'll have to check for that first; since attempting to invoke `decode()` method on `None` would produce an error. You'll also have to be sure the bytes represent a valid string, in the character encoding being used for the decoding/conversion.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to why a bytearray is returned rather than bytes?

Comment: I do not know why the library authors used the mutable bytearray instead of immutable bytes. Maybe the implementation constructs the result by modifying a bytearray, so it was more efficient to just return it (rather than adding another operation to convert it to bytes to return).

Answer (score 0):

Much easier...

[How to return str from MySQL using mysql.connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566078/how-to-return-str-from-mysql-using-mysql-connector)

Adding mysql-connector-python==8.0.17 to requirements.txt resolved this issue for me

"pip install mysql-connector-python" from terminal