# Encoding issue in python using mysql connector python

Tags: python, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

I have written a python script which get data from database and process it.
Initially I was using pymysql for connecting database which I changed to MySQL Connector for python. When I started using MySQL Connector I am getting following issue

**'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-16: ordinal not in range(128)**

I tried by adding charset settings of MySQL Connector but issue still persists.

Do anyone have idea on this issue?

Comment: Paste code sample please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make sure that in your table you have specified a `ascii` encoding

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
     col1 char, 
     ....,
     ....,
     ....
)Engine=InnoDB charset=ascii;
```

2. In the MySQL-Python connector specify `assci` encoding and enable unicode

`db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port=3306,
    user="john",
    passwd="megajonhy",
    db="jonhydb",
    use_unicode=True,
    charset='ascii'
)`

I believe that by default `use_unicode` is set to `False`, and thus by setting it `True` you will fix the issue.

Comment: This did not help at all for my `utf8mb4` database when I used `use_unicode=True, charset='utf8'`. What did help was [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836817/2550406)