# MySQL Table read into Python

Tags: python, mysql

```
cursor.execute('SELECT userid,productid,description from goqii_store_product_rating_log')
```

Above is the query I am trying to read from MySQL database using python.

Here the *Datatype for description column is TEXT*.

When I run this I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8: character maps to

How can I overcome this error and read the data smoothly??.

Python Version used : 3.7.3

Regards

Comment: I think the question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598350/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8d-in-position-7240-cha

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Hello Gaurav,This is basically while reading a csv file right,Here i am directly importing the data through a SQL query how do I handle it then.Can you help me with a code Snippet as I am new to Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question has already been answered here:

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7240: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598350/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8d-in-position-7240-cha)

This seems to be an issue that has been caused by encoding differences.

A way to work around this has been pointed out here as well. Hope this helps: [How to return str from MySQL using mysql.connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566078/how-to-return-str-from-mysql-using-mysql-connector/43836817#43836817)

Also, you need to provide more details while posting the question such as the connector you used (eg: PyMySQL)

Try something on these lines:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='username',
                       passwd='password',
                       db='database',
                       charset='utf8')
```

Comment: I am using MySQLdb package and MYsqldb.connect() to make the connection

Comment: When you connect() to your database, pass the charset='utf8' parameter.

Comment: Hello Gaurav,I was able to read it using the pymysql connector .Thanks a Tonne111

Comment: I did upvoted the answer but it isnt changing,Don't know why

Comment: Specifying charset="utf-8" worked for me to decode utf8mb4 encoding.