# how-to query mysql utf-8 table using ASCII

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have created a mysql 5.6 table with a column encoded in utf-8, for characters in **Romanian, Czech, Hungarian, Polish, French, German, Scandinavian** language(s) - i.e. european characters, but quite non-ASCII.

However, i would like to query this column using just ASCII characters - e.g. in the LIKE clause- so that **ă,î,â,ș,ț,ü,ä,ö** etc. characters can be (succesfully) queried using **a,e,i,o,u,s,t** etc.

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cheat sheet for knowing what letters map "equal" under what collations in [utf8 collations](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)  It agrees that `Ł` is not mapped to `L` for any collation.  `general_ci` sorts it after `Z`; `utf8_unicode_520_ci` sorts it with `L`; the rest sort it before `M`.

`polish_ci` treats `Ę` as distinct from the rest of the `E`-like characters.  Ditto for `Ą`.  The Baltic states tend to keep certain accented consonants separate.

In `polish_ci`, `Ń` (hex `C584`) collates after `N` and before `O`; the other collations treate it equal to `N`.

**utf8_unicode_520_ci** is probably the best collation for you.

Also, you might consider "combining" accents -- where two utf8 'characters' "combine" to make a single characters.  `utf8_unicode_ci` collates 'correctly' for most of them, as seen [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#utf8_collations_examples).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see it possible by any conventional way using only SQL.
You only can write query preprocessor, that will automatically replace ascii characters with european. 
https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php - assuming you are using PHP
But you still need to feed every query to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my question:

If the character set you define for the column is **utf8_general_ci**, then many, (if not all) **flavors** of **a,e,o,u** will be found by a query using **plain a,e,o,u**.
I even found the **n** in Wołoszyńska using **plain** n.

UNFORTUNATELY, the lowercase L "with oblique bar" in the same word was not found.

The answer was suggested by dddd's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php)

Comment: Have you tried `utf8_unicode_ci` as well? It contains additional mappings (though not sure if it specifically covers your L).

Comment: @deceze Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've noticed that "important sites" refrain from using it and instead use the plain L.