# Mysql table configuration to insert and select different languages

Tags: mysql, collation, create-table

I am building a web site with a form. This form may be filled in different languages (from English and Spanish to Japanese and Arabic)

I have two questions:

Knowing that, how would you configure the mysql table where the data is going to be stored?

My web is UTF8, is that correct?

Comment: yes, utf8 is the best for your

Comment: use utf8, `utf8_general_ci`. Why? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/367725/889852 P.S.: I suggest you allways use UTF8, and on damand you can optimize for specific language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will be accepting Chinese, too, then go all the way -- use `utf8mb4`.  That is a superset of utf8; to handle a few more Chinese characters.

For collation, `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is probably the best overall.