# Which MySQL collation exactly matches PHP's string comparison?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding, collation

Here is a MySQL query:

```
SELECT last_name FROM users ORDER BY last_name
```

We get all that data into PHP and then run:

```
$prior = NULL;
do {
    $current = array_shift($results);
    assert($current >= $prior);
    $prior = $current;
} while ($current !== NULL);
```

Currently this assertion fails for certain inputs. Is it possible to add a COLLATE clause to the MySQL query above to absolutely guarantee that PHP assertion?

---

Stuff I tried:

- The above code, it doesn't work for certain non-ASCII inputs
- `ORDER BY email COLLATE utf8_bin` resulted in `COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`
- Maybe this is a duplicate of [What is the best collation to use for MySQL with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php) but that seemed more subjective, I am seeking a specific answer to a specific problem

---

Others notes:

- If it makes a difference, this column is `latin1`
- My PHP PDO wrapper library is https://github.com/fulldecent/thin-pdo

Comment: where are you setting `$next` ?

Comment: you could do `ORDER BY email COLLATE 'latin1_bin'` or you could say set your collation of the column to `utf8`, but you can't collate by a different sub set in your query.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a `latin1` column in 2016? That seems overly restrictive.

Comment: @cmorrissey, thank you code corrected

Comment: @tadman Thank you, I reported upstream https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2530

Comment: You can [set the default encoding and collation at the database level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html) if you want. This might not be the fault of Sequel Pro here if your defaults are `latin1`. As people really like to use things like emoji lately, you may want to go one further and use `utf8mb4` as a default.

Comment: What `CHARACTER SET` are you using?  It sounds like latin1.  Perhaps you wanted utf8 instead?  (It's hard to address your question without knowing these details.)

Comment: @RickJames it is latin1 character set

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ('a' == 'A') ? 'a==A ' : 'a <> A ';
echo ('a' == 'á') ? 'a==á ' : 'a <> á ';
```

Both came back `<>`, so I deduce that PHP acts like `latin1_bin` (or the `_bin` of whatever charset you have).