# Issue with php when i try to insert data on MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

When I insert some data in the mysql with a form in my system it saves everything wrong, but if I insert manually through the phpmyadmin it goes smoothly and save everything OK.

in my html there is the meta tag saying charset UTF-8, and in my php ini, the charset says UTF-8.

To read the database theres no problem but to insert in it goes wrong, it was working just fine but somehow it stoped working and started doing this.

If i insert in the form this phrase

> Soluções Técnicas

in the data base saves

> SoluÃ§Ãµes TÃ©cnica

Comment: We can't help you without you showing your code. Please, take the [tour].

Comment: What is the error you are getting, Please post your error message

Comment: If i insert in the form this phrase Soluções Técnicas, in the data base saves SoluÃ§Ãµes TÃ©cnica

Comment: Sounds like your DB has the wrong [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/367711/2191572 | https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/109982/103990 | https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76788/29510

Comment: The Collation I set in the DB is utf8_general_ci and the field in the table is the same

Comment: Check your actual PHP file. Is IT in utf-8?

Comment: Sorry ,but which one ? I have a lot of forms in the system the only thing they share in common are the Header and Footer Files.

Comment: Are you able to output from old data from MySQL -> PHP -> YUOR page with special characters using same php file you work with?

Comment: Yes, the old data is OK in the DB. When I do the SELECT it brings everything just like the DB including the new bugged data. The problem is the data inserted through the form

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Collation affects ordering and string comparisons. This is an *encoding* issue.