# utf8mb4_unicode_ci OR utf8mb4_danish_ci

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

Both `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_danish_ci` (mysql/mariadb database) seems to work fine on my danish website.

When I test for characters/symbols/emojis, they both seem to display the same result.
Danish letters like æ/ø/å works in both.

**Why would I choose one charset/collation over the other?**

Does `utf8mb4_danish_ci` add characters/codes or is it actually more narrow than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`?

Comment: The charset is `utf8mb4`. `utf8mb4_danish_ci` is the collation which "is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set".

Comment: So why choose utf8mb4_unicode_ci over utf8mb4_danish_ci or reversed?

Comment: It is for comparison, not storage. `characters/symbols/emojis` will not be an issue, nor `characters/codes`. They both support the same character set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php

Comment: Ok. I doubt I will be comparing utf8 characters/codes, only iso characters. The utf8mb4 is just to give users the ability to use emoji's etc. in a text field on my website. So I guess it's more a matter of performance? (in my case)

Comment: Yup, or my understanding of it at least. I'll leave it to someone with more experience in case there are nuisances I'm missing though.

Comment: part of SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'utf8mb4'; result:utf8mb4_danish_ci          | utf8mb4 | 235 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     |
utf8mb4_unicode_ci         | utf8mb4 | 224 |         | Yes      |       8 | PAD SPACE     | they are same

Comment: An example I like is Spanish: `ch` used to be a letter of its own so dictionaries looked like `canada
corea
china`. The rule changed and it was split into c and h so dictionaries were updated to `canada
china
corea`. Same language, same characters, same encoding but two different collations to choose from ("traditional" and "modern").

Comment: @yaoweijq - The meat is behind the column with `235` vs `224`; the collations _are_ different.  And especially different in the 3 'characters' the OP mentioned.

Comment: @mowgli - "Encoding" is one thing; "Collation" is another.  `ch` is _encoded_ the same in all `CHARACTER SETs`, but sorts different in `utf8_spanish2_ci` (and czech, lithuanian, and slovak collations).  In utf8_lithuanian_ci, `c=ch`.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Comment: (For this European languages, character sets `utf8` and `utf8mb4` are identical, except for name.)

Comment: @RickJames 235 vs 224 is only the identifier, i think actually they are the same, as other columns values are all the same.

Comment: @yaoweijq - But all the collation information is behind that identifier, in some file or code somewhere.  The _encoding_ is the same (both are utf8mb4); the _collation_ is different.

Answer (score 2):

To distinguish and sort Emoji, I think you need `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, which is based on Unicode 5.20.  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is based on the older 4.0.  (I don't know `_danish_` compares Emoji.)  MySQL 8.0 will introduce the 9.0 version: `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

For `utf8mb4_danish_ci`:  `æ/ø/å` each sort after `z`. That is `y < z < æ < ø < å`

For `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, `æ` acts like a letter between `a` and `b`'; `ø` between `o` and `p`; `å=a`

For `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` and `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`: `æ=ae`; `ø=o`; `å=a`

It all depends on whether you care about how those three characters compare (`WHERE`) and sort (`ORDER BY`) as above.

More details and more collations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

You did not ask, but it seems that *danish* says `Ä=Æ=ä=æ < Ö=Ø=ö=ø < Aa=Å=å < Þ=þ`; those seem to cater toward Icelandic and Swedish.